# How to make active an item from the main navigation menu in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, menu, menuitem

In the Main Header Navigation I have this links:

> **Home | Events | About | Blog**

I want when I go to Blog page and select a post, to be able to make active in the header menu the ***"Blog"*** item.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('nav_menu_css_class' , 'custom_nav_class' , 10 , 2);
function custom_nav_class ($classes, $item) {
    if (in_array('current-menu-item', $classes) ){
        $classes[] = 'active ';
    }
    return $classes;
}
```

You can add above code in your active theme `functions.php` .

---

#### CSS

```
li.active {
    background: #3FAEA5;
    color:#fff;
}
li.active a {
    text-decoration: underline;
    background:#ccc;
}
```